# Superposition Theorem Question

Tags: power-electronics

Calculate I' in figure 8-14(a)

I need help on finding I'

RT= 1/4+1/4+1/2 = 1

RT= 4+2+1=7

Then i applied ohm's law to find the current

IT=14/7=2mA

Am i calculating anything wrong?

[image: superposition theorem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first calculation is wrong, but the whole idea is correct. The resistance seen by the supply is:
$$
((4\Omega\ s\ 2\Omega)\ p\ 4\Omega)\ s\ 4\Omega\ s\ 2\Omega
$$
where \$x s y\$ means "x in series with y" while \$x p y\$ means "x parallel y". Let's do the math:
$$
((4\Omega\ s\ 2\Omega)\ p\ 4\Omega)\ s\ 4\Omega\ s\ 2\Omega=(6\Omega\ p\ 4\Omega)\ s\ 6\Omega= 2.4\Omega\ s\ 6\Omega = 8.4\Omega
$$
The total current then is:
$$I_{tot}=\frac{14V}{8.4\Omega}=1.67A$$
Now you can calculate \$I'\$ using the current divider law between the \$4\Omega\$ vertical resistor and \$4\Omega\ s\ 2\Omega\$:
$$
I'=I_{tot}\cdot\frac{4\Omega}{(4\Omega\ s\ 2\Omega) + 4\Omega}=1.67A\cdot\frac{4\Omega}{10\Omega}=0.67A
$$